# finding unmatched record mysql

Tags: mysql

I have one table Orders which have OrderId and OrderName columns.

```
OrderId  |    OrderName
------------------------
  1      |          food
-------------------------
  2      |          milk
----------------------
  3      |     veg
----------------------
  4      |     banana
------------------------
```

i want to match order id with few random orders ids like 3,5,6,2,1.I want only order id which doesn't match like 5,6.Please help me with the query.

Thanks.

Comment: I am kind of confused, what results do you want?

Comment: I have certain set of Order Ids(Say someone gave me some random Order IDs and he/she wants me to Add Order Ids which is not there in Tables).Now i want to know match only Order ids which is not there in Database.Make sense?

Comment: @user3209114...   Does "Say someone gave me some random Order IDs and he/she wants me to Add Order Ids which is not there in Tables" means that you have want to compare the 'OrderId' of 'Orders' table with another table data.Am I correct??

Answer (score 0):

As you don't want to fetch order ids 5 and 6, so you can exclude these orders by below query-

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders 
WHERE OrderID NOT IN(5,6);
```

**Update as per user requirement:**

```
    SELECT a.myid as OrderId FROM 
    (
SELECT a.m*10000+b.n*1000+c.p*100+d.q*10+e.r AS  myid FROM 
(SELECT 0 m UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) a
JOIN 
(SELECT 0 n UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) b 
JOIN 
(SELECT 0 p UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) c 
JOIN 
(SELECT 0 q UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) d 
JOIN 
(SELECT 0 r UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) e 
ORDER BY myid
    ) a 
    LEFT JOIN orders b ON a.myid=b.orderid 
    WHERE a.myid IN (1,2,3,11,12,6) AND b.orderid IS NULL;
```

Just put your orders list in a.myid() and execute above query.

Further If your own orders are more then we can modify query accordingly.

Comment: I want only 5, and 6.Whole idea is to get Orders ids which is not there in the table.

Comment: Please check updated query if your are facing any issue then please let me know.

Comment: Hey its works for me ,but say i have 1000 order ids,do you have any better solution for this?

Comment: I have updated query which can take care upto 99999 orders and same way you can increase limit.

Comment: Thanks for your effort,So basically this is very specific to Integers.Is it possible to make it generic for other variables?